# Compare Columns Where One is Similar to Part of Another Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, compare

I'm would like to write a `Select` query where I can see if one column is like part of another in postgresql.

**tblNames**:

```
ID    Description                Name
-----------------------------------------
1     Global Solutions           Dell
2     News from TV               Fake
3     The Zebra company          Zebra
```

The query should return:

```
3 | The Zebra company | Zebra
```

I tried different ways without success.

```
WHERE ISNULL(CHARINDEX("Name", Description), 0) = 0
```

or

```
WHERE '%' + "Name" + '%' NOT LIKE "Description";
```

However `CHARINDEX` does not exist in PSQL.

Comment: Solved: WHERE "Description" LIKE '%'  || "Name" || '%'  
Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

To search, you need to use the expression:
`"Description" like ('%' || "Name" || '%')`